# Why is the eigenvalues-eigenvectors equation rarely seen in matricial format?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

Given a square matrix $\mathbf{A}$, its eigenvalues $\lambda$ and eigenvectors $\vec{\mathbf{v}} $ are, by definition, the solutions to the following equation:
$$
\mathbf{A} \cdot \vec{\mathbf{v}} = \lambda \cdot \vec{\mathbf{v}}
$$

Say $\left\{\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \dots, \lambda_n\right\}$ is the set of eigenvalues and $\mathbf{\Lambda} $ is a diagonal matrix composed by these eigenvalues:
$$
\mathbf{\Lambda} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & \lambda_2 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & \lambda_n \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Say $\left\{\vec{\mathbf{v}_1}, \vec{\mathbf{v}_2}, \dots, \vec{\mathbf{v}_n}\right\}$ is the set of eigenvectors and $\mathbf{V}$ is a square matrix composed by these eigenvectors:
$$
\mathbf{V} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\vec{\mathbf{v}_1} & \vec{\mathbf{v}_2} & \cdots & \vec{\mathbf{v}_n}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Then the eigenvalues-eigenvectores relation can be written in a matricial form:
$$
\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{V} = \mathbf{V} \cdot \mathbf{\Lambda}
$$

However, I rarely see this format anywhere. Why? Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: That assumes there are $n$ eigenvectors. There are not always $n$ eigenvectors.

Comment: The best you can do in general is get a $\Lambda$ in Jordan Normal Form. But if there are $n$ distinct eigenvaluea, you can always get a diagonal matrix.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form

Comment: In general, we write it as $V^{-1}AV=\Lambda.$

Comment: But the heart is you want to see that eigenvalues and eigenvectors are a property of the linear transformation, not the matrix representation (which depends on a specific basis for your vector space.)

Comment: Thanks @ThomasAndrews! I had not notice that the matricial format only holds true when all eigenvalues are distinct. Feel free to write an asnwer!

Comment: Well, it sometimes works when there are duplicate eigenvalues. Only when the matrix is diagonalizable, though.